# CSS Min width / Margin percentage issue

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(../i/bck.gif);
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrap{
    min-width:1000px;
    width:68%;
    margin:0 16%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">a</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I messed with the code for a little bit now, and found that the problem stands at min-width. If you resize (make smaller) the browser, you will see that it will keep a margin of 16% on the left, while the width is not 68% any more, but 1000px, which may be more than 68% when a browser window is smaller. Now, the question is does anyone know of workaround for this?

Example 1:
Browser Width: 2000px, div width: 68% -> 1360px, margin left+right: 16% -> 320px each.

Example 2:
Browser Width: 1200px, div width: 1000px (min), margin left+right: 16% -> 192p each.

Example 2 is the problem. Since 68% of the browser is less than 1000px, the div gets a width of 1000px. 1000px + 192px + 192px is not equal to the full size of the browser which is 1200px.

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: I posted the original question on my iphone and realized i wasn't thorough. I edited the original question. See if you have a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the concept, and it seems to work as expected.

```
<div>foo</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div { width: 80%; margin: 0 10%; }
```

Your selector is an id, unless the `div` has `id="div"`, the selector has to change. And the capitalization of the attributes matters.

Comment: I posted the original question on my iphone and realized i wasn't thorough. I edited the original question. See if you have a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#wrap {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 16%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, but it does not do anything in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
margin: 0 16%;
```

Instead of specifying margin-left and margin-right, you could also tell the browser to calculate them:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That way, if your `#wrap` is 68% wide, your margins will be 16% (or 17%, but rounding is not your problem here). If your `#wrap` is 1000px wide, the left and right margins will still be equal. But they will be less than 16%.

Just to be complete, your html should start with a valid doctype declaration.

Comment: Oh this drives me nuts. margin:0 auto; would not work with position:absolute. I took position absolute off by adding another wrapper and making everything relative thereafter. Also, this is not the actual html/css but just something i put together to test why my page wasn't working. was it the css, another element on the page or what. Thanks.